# Update or change adapter in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sqlite, android-arrayadapter

I have question for list-view please see my below code

```
private void set_adapter() {

    Cursor list_scan_curson = scan_result.getScanResult();
    List<String> list_scan = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {

        if (list_scan_curson.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String name = list_scan_curson.getString(0);

                // Adding contact to list
                list_scan.add(name);
            } while (list_scan_curson.moveToNext());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> list_item_scan = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_scan);
        this.list_scan.setAdapter(list_item_scan);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

now i want to change or update adapter when my database update and based on that list-view will update so can any buddy tell me how to do this

Comment: update the underlying data the populates your listview and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: will change my cursor data ?? or get updated data from database ??

Comment: use some CursorAdapter based class + ContentProvider and you will nor have to do anyrhing

Comment: @pskink can u tell me how to implement ??

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You create a new cursor, and replace the old one, something like this:

```
Private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter; // adapter declared as field
...
mAdapter =  ..., // create adapter
...
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // update listview
```

Comment: `mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);` this method is not available with ArrayAdapter

Comment: My mistake. With an ArrayAdapter you do not need to change the cursor all. You can just ignore that bit.

Comment: well this is not working please check my code i am using cursor so tell me how can i refresh cursor ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update data from list use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. If you want to update data from database you have to trigger some actions so use `onScrollchanged` listener or use some background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some logic like below[`checkIstheDataVersionChanged(Object CurrentVersion)`] to check what type of change/update will affect your dataset and reload the listView using set_adapter.

```
boolean isDataSetChanged = checkIstheDataVersionChanged(Object CurrentVersion);

if(isDataSetChanged )
{
 set_adapter();
}
```

Comment: this is not updating list-view even i clear adapter and call set_adapter() still not updating